# Sort part of DataFrame in Python Panda, return new column with order depending on row values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My first question here, I hope this is understandable.

I have a Panda DataFrame:

|  | order_numbers | x_closest_autobahn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 34 | 3 |
| 1 | 11 | 3 |
| 2 | 5 | 3 |
| 3 | 8 | 12 |
| 4 | 2 | 12 |

I would like to get a new column with the order_number per closest_autobahn in ascending order:

|  | order_numbers | x_closest_autobahn | order_number_autobahn_x |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 5 | 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 11 | 3 | 2 |
| 0 | 34 | 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 12 | 1 |
| 3 | 8 | 12 | 2 |

I have tried:

```py
df['order_number_autobahn_x'] = ([df.loc[(df['x_closest_autobahn'] == 3)]].sort_values(by=['order_numbers'], ascending=True, inplace=True))
```

I have looked at slicing, sort_values and reset_index

```py
df.sort_values(by=['order_numbers'], ascending=True, inplace=True)
 
df = df.reset_index()  # reset index to the order after sort

df['order_numbers_index'] = df.index
```

but I can't seem to get the DataFrame I am looking for.

Comment: sort by both columns in the desired order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by both columns and for counter use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df = df.sort_values(['x_closest_autobahn','order_numbers'])

df['order_number_autobahn_x'] = df.groupby('x_closest_autobahn').cumcount().add(1)
print (df)
   order_numbers  x_closest_autobahn  order_number_autobahn_x
2              5                   3                        1
1             11                   3                        2
0             34                   3                        3
4              2                  12                        1
3              8                  12                        2
```

Comment: WOW, that answer was fast! Thank you. and so elegant!